# How to render a template in Sitecore, if it does not have a content item

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

This seems to be a very simple concept, but I am unable to resolve. What I'm trying to do is, render/display a Standard value of a template, to the page.
Created the items & templates using Rocks. Here is the structure.

**1. Sublayout - footer.ascx**

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>This is a title.</h1>
    <p>All the content goes here</p>
    <sc:placeholder runat="server" Key="footercontent" />   
</div>
```

**2. Sublayout - StickyNav.ascx**

```
<a class="btn" href="#">
     <sc:Text Field="Sticky Nav Title" runat="server" />            
 </a>
```

**3. Template - Sticky Nav**
[image]
[image]

The first pic is of the template & the second one shows the assigned default value in _Standard Values.
Then, in Sitecore Explorer,
`right clicked on (Sticky Nav - _Standard Values) > Tasks > Design Layout on Standard Values`.
[image]
Now, there is a content item "index" under /sitecore/content/. It has these layouts declared:
[image]
When I right click on `Index > Tools > Browse  > Preview`, the index page does open and the footer content is also displayed.

But, I am unable to see the text 'Go To Top', that was set as a Standard value (Image 2). It is empty.

What am i missing here.

Comment: There are no comments around it!

Comment: Make sure that all your templates, renderings and content items are published. You can do this by changing to the web database and viewing the items in the content editor.

Comment: I am working only in master. The only publish I do is the Visual studio publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the initial thought itself was a mistake. There HAS to be an item if it's value has to be displayed on page.

So, I created a new item under `/sitecore/content/Sticky Nav Button` using the template `Sticky Nav`.

And in StickyNav.ascx, updated the control as:

`<sc:Text Field="Sticky Nav Title" runat="server" DataSource = "/sitecore/content/Sticky Nav Button"/>`

Hope this helps beginners like me.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few factors blocking the content being showed. For the front end the best bet is to rule out things like publishing - i.e. make sure that the template, fields, standard values, and the content items are all published correctly. If you are in preview this is probably of less relevance but worth noting when you deploy

When the `sc:Text` control renders is will be running the `renderField` pipeline. At the point that interacts it will be talking to Sitecore via the api.

To check things via the code behind for your control (assuming it's an ascx due to the runat="server" tag). Check:

```
Field field = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Sticky Nav Title"];

if (field != null)
{
    string value = field.Value;
}
```

And debug through to check the field actually has the value you require.

In the cms, when you view the page of interest does the 'Sticky Nav Title' field appear to have a value, and be the value you are interested in?

Comment: In cms, there is no value. I did this in page_load to check `if (field != null){}else{Response.write("000");}` and the output is 000. A beginner here, I do not know how to do debug like for a VS .net project. Tried but failed

Comment: How did you add the `__standard values` item to your template? It sounds like that either isn't linked up correctly or doesn't have the data set correctly. To validate this you need to check a couple places (see screenshots in 2s)

Comment: 1. If you are on the template, see the builder section of the ribbon, click 'Standard Values'. This should take you to a child of the original item, called `__Standard Values`. On this item fill out the field you want in the language you are interested (http://screencast.com/t/xwPkeCr0wHER).  Then on the content item, check the [standard value] attribute shows next to the field you want.

Comment: The Standard value doesn't show up for `index`. Clearly missing something here. How come the footer gets rendered fine. plz check the images I have updated in Question

Comment: It looks like the item in question (index) doesnt implement that template, either directly or via template inheritance. What type of template does index use? The quick info bar should show that.

Comment: index uses a template called `Base Page`. This template only has layout (main) & sublayout (footer) set.

Comment: It might be worth reading http://gettingtoknowsitecore.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/inheritance-content-modeling-sitecore.html to help get to grips with the template inheritance you need

Comment: Did you create the item before you put in the standard value of 'Go To Top' in the standard values? Standard values are only applied when you create an item. Applying standard values after an item has been created doesn't propagate the values down to the item.